# Increase the Number of partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

We are working on Confluent Platform and we are still getting to know the internals. But we have implemented generic use cases . We are trying to optimizing our cluster

In my use case, I need to increase the number of partitions of a topic . What is the impact of it ? Can you please share of it

Comment: Have a look at this blog: https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can increase partitions.

**However**,

1. Increasing partitions does not move *existing* data. If using Confluent Enterprise, you could use `confluent-rebalancer`, or if not, then `kafka-reassign-partitions` CLI tool. So, you'll definitely want to rebalance a topic to "optimize" the cluster.
2. During the retention period of the topic (read: for the existing data), if you previously had a producer sending data to partition `N`, and now had `N+1` partitions, then you lose ordering of those messages that solely existed in partition `N`. New messages could be spread across new partitions that a new producer calculates with the `DefaultPartitioner`. If you don't send keys with messages, then this isn't a problem.